# Why Appium Inspector can not 'tap'?

Tags: testing, appium, appium-inspector

I'm using Appium Inspector to check the element of app.
But when I start a session, the app on android mobile can be invoked, but the screen on inspector is just dark, even the splash screen of app can not be displayed.
And the screen on inspector can not be tapped. When I tap, a [loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSFQZ.png) will appear and after a while, it shows that `fail to tapped`.

Do you have any ideas about this?

Comment: In the Appium Inspector, there is a refresh icon on the menu bar that's shown on the top. What happens when you click on it, does it load the page? If not, you might want to check the Appium server logs and see if there is any error loading the screenshot of the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the option in the Inspector to select by source (the standard select option) Appium sometimes cannot make a distinction between overlay/underlay elements which aren't interactable.

There are several options you have in order to navigate and test smoothly in Appium to make your life a bit easier:

*Option 1:* Is to use the option **Tap by coordinates**. If you only need to navigate through Appium, this option makes your life a easier. It's just like you are touching the screen and mostly Appium works great for exploring through the app.

*Option 2:* After exploring through the app and making sure the clickpath or any testcase you have is solide, you can start to identify the elements you really need. !The behaviour of the Inspector can differ widely from the real AndroidDriver/AppiumDriver and therefore you can more safely use `MobileElement(@FindBy).Click();`! . Try and look for the most logical element in the XML tree (i.e. elements with *button* or *input*).